# MySQL: counts by week.

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to group a series of counts but by week. I know that using the week() function returns a number for the week, but i'd like something like this:

```
Week                 count(*)
Jan 1 - Jan 7        30
Jan 8 - 14           50

and so on...
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you always want to start on Jan 1? If so what do you want to happen with the last week? There will almost always be weeks that are in both years.

Comment: Can you share the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  
concat(cast(DATE_ADD(yourdate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(yourdate)) DAY) as char), ' - ',
cast(DATE_ADD(yourdate, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(yourdate)) DAY) as char))
as period, count(*) 
from tablename 
group by week(yourdate)
```

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way to eliminate the minutes and seconds? Maybe like a truncation or something? Thanks.

Comment: is it a `datetime` or `timestamp` datatype? you can use a `DATE` function. like `DATE(yourdate)`

Comment: Be aware that if your table holds values from more than one year you'll want to change the group by clause to include the year, or you'll get counts from multiple years rolled into one (unless that is what you want).